# Datastore error using Google cloud app-engine flexible quick start

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I have started using Google Cloud Flexible using the following link: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart

I have tried to read all the readme file and follow the instruction, but when i try to execute the maven command (mvn clean gcloud:deploy) to deploy in loacalhost, I see the following error about the datastore:

```
Caused by: com.google.datastore.v1.client.DatastoreException: Unexpected OK error code with HTTP status code of 401. Message: ., code=INTERNAL
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:126)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.makeException(RemoteRpc.java:163)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.RemoteRpc.call(RemoteRpc.java:89)
    at com.google.datastore.v1.client.Datastore.runQuery(Datastore.java:108)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.DefaultDatastoreRpc.runQuery(DefaultDatastoreRpc.java:162)
```

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what was the problem. As it has been explained in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server), to use Datastore in localhost, you should use the local Datastore emulator. So the reason I had the mentioned error, was that I have not set up the the local Datastore emulator, but I could deploy the project in app-engine without any error.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Datastore emulator not running.
You can use command to start the emulator, set environment variable for it, then start your application:

1)Start Datastore in a separate command window:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore start
```

2)Set environment variables:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore env-init > set_vars.cmd && set_vars.cmd
```

3)Start app using mvn:

```
mvn jetty:run-exploded
```

Those commands are for windows platform. The full details are here: 
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator